# jQuery use href with images

Tags: jquery

Could someone help me to make these 2 lines able to use href on click image?

In current status, each images showing link out as go. I just wanted images to be clickable to hrefs

```
$.each( images, function( i, imageName ) {

$('<a data-name="'+ imageName +'" href="'+ pathPrefix + 
   imageName +'-button-1'+'">go</a>').appendTo('#images'));
 $('<img data-name="'+ imageName +'" src="'+ pathPrefix + 
   imageName +'-button-1'+'.jpg">').appendTo('#images');
});
```

the below use doesn`t work as required.
It fails on adding hrefs to the images

```
 $.each( images, function( i, imageName ) {
    $('<a data-name="'+ imageName +'" href="">go</a>').appendTo($('<img data-name="'+ 
      imageName +'" src="'+ pathPrefix + 
      imageName +'-button-1'+'.jpg">').appendTo('#images'));
 });
```

Comment: Your description is a bit confusing, but I think you want the image to be clickable? If you want the image to be clickable, the `<img` tag needs to be inside the `<a href` tag. e.g. `<a href="https://www.example.com"><img src="https://www.example.com/xyz.jpg"/></a>` something like that

Comment: this usage doesnt work on my function..

$('<a data-name="'+ imageName +'" href="'+ pathPrefix + imageName +'-button-1'+'"><img data-name="'+ imageName +'" src="'+ pathPrefix + imageName +'-button-1'+'.jpg"></a>').appendTo('#images'));
});

Comment: thank you Satpal..This one also broke my original function for each images..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is SO much more readable

Also remove the > from #images > like here codepen.io/mplungjan/pen/OJVQmoN

```js
const pathPrefix = "https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.png&text=";
const images = ["img1","img2"]
$.each(images, function(i, imageName) {
  const $container = $('#images');
  const $a = $('<a/>', {
    "data-name": imageName,
    "href": pathPrefix + imageName + '-button-1' })
  const $img = $('<img/>', {
    "data-name": imageName,
    "src": pathPrefix + imageName + '-button-1' + '.jpg'
  })
  $a.append($img)
    .append("go");
  $container.append($a)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="images"></div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209480/discussion-on-answer-by-mplungjan-jquery-use-href-with-images).